# SQL select max of boolean value on columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two boolean type columns in my table. I want to make a select on these two columns according to these conditions:
for each column:

- if at least one line = 1, I put @result =1
- if no line = 1, I put @result = 0

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test
> (
>     active1 bit,
>     active2 bit,
> )
>
> INSERT INTO test(active1 , active2 )
>  VALUES
>  (0,0),
>  (1;0),
>  (0.0);
> ```

it must return @result1= 1 and @result2= 0 ,I want to do this in a single query, I tried with MAX but it didn't work :

```
declare @result1 bit
declare @result1 bit
select 
@result1= max(active1), @result2= max(active2)
from test
```

Help please

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky the code for the creation of the table and the insertion is already written, you can't see it!!! there is even the query that I used

Comment: After correcting all the typos in your code (no one should need to do that for you), you should encounter the error "Msg 8117 Level 16 State 1 Line 5 Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator." When you encounter errors you should post the complete error message and not useless phrases like "didn't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot perform aggregations on `bit` columns, you need to cast them to a suitable data type

```
declare @result1 bit, @result2 bit;

with t as (
    select Convert(tinyint, active1) active1, Convert(tinyint, active2) active2
    from test
)
select @result1=max(active1), @result2= max(active2)
from t;

select @result1 Result1, @result2 Result2;
```

(note also that bit columns are *not* booleans)